# Where does phpinfo() get its info?

Tags: php

If you run a `phpinfo();` does it show exactly what is in the php.ini or if settings are changed on the fly via php with methods like `ini_set()` or via `.htaccess` will they be shown in phpinfo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/phpinfo) shows, in the "*Local Value*" column, the current configuration ; i.e.

- what is in `php.ini`
- eventually, overriden in Apache's `VirtualHost` or in `.htaccess` files
- eventually, overriden by `ini_set`

In the end, it shows the configuration values that would be / are used by your script.

As a sidenote : it also display informations that are not-really "configuration" per-se, like the configure line that was used to compile PHP, the version of the Zend Engine, ...

Answer (score 1):

It will show the current running environment, not just what is in php.ini. Anything that changes the environment like the methods you mentioned will be reflected.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's what the meaning of the  "global" and "local" columns is - "global" is what's set in the central php.ini, "local" is whatever changes have been applied to the global setting using one of the methods you describe.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `ini_set()`, the changes are made on-the-fly for the **current** script only, it does not permanently change `php.ini` settings. The `phpinfo()` shows current settings of what is there in the `php.ini` file which is also influenced by apache and `ini_set` function.

Answer (score 0):

`phpinfo()` always display the settings value in 2 column. First column is the global value that set in `php.ini` file. Second column is per user value, that set in `php.ini` or can be override by `.htaccess` file or override through `ini_set` before calling `phpinfo()`.

Please note that not all settings value can be override by `.htaccess` or `ini_set`. See the complete list [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php) and take a look at Changeable column. See the explanation og the Changeable column value [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php).

Try it by yourself.